# How to select last hour and groupby minute?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to select data from SQL database using EF, select the last hour and then group by minute.

```
var result = _dbContext.views
             .Where(x => x.Id == id && x.Created  > DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1))
             .OrderBy(x => x.Created)
             .GroupBy(x=> x.Created.Where({Range is 1 minute}));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` instance has a `Minute` property which is an `int` so you can use the `x.Created.Minute` for grouping:

```
var result = _dbContext.views
             .Where(x => x.Id == id && x.Created  > DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1))
             .OrderBy(x => x.Created)
             .GroupBy(x=> x.Created.Minute}));
```

Comment: Ah, so simple. Thank you